# Does C# have an enum that would match SQL object type?

Tags: sql, enums

In the sys.objects table [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), there's a list of types with their corresponding codes:

- SO = Sequence object
- U = Table (user-defined)
- V = View
  ...

Is there a native enum or const in C# that would match these Sql object type?

The closest enum I've found is the [DAC ObjectType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.objecttype?view=sql-dacfx-150) but it only matches some of the Sql object type.

Since SQL server is using 2 characters codes for these type, I understand that I would probably have write some mapping logic... but I'd prefer using a native enum instead of writing my own Enum.

Comment: SQL object type?

Comment: This is the name used in documentation.  I'm not sure if there's a better way to describe these values.

Comment: You could ask yourself why the DAC ObjectType enum would exist *if* there was such an enum.

Comment: Maybe you can enlight me on the purpose of the DAC ObjectType Enum.  Documentation say it defines object types that exist in SQL Server so I was expecting them to be linked.  Obviously, they're not so I'm clearly missing the point about one of these type.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a native enum or const in C# that would match these Sql object type?

No.  There is not.